# How do I tally and plot different combinations of variables in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, tidyverse

I am trying to visualize the information in the variables of the following dataset:

```
BinVar-1 BinVar-2 MultiVar-1 MultiVar-2 Region
  0          0       0         0          Africa
  0          1       1         0          Europe
  0          1       2         0          Asia
  1          0       0         1          Asia
  1          0       3         2          Europe
  1          1       4         3          Africa
  0          0       5         4          Africa
  1          1       5         4          Asia
  0          0       3         2          Asia
  0          0       3         2          Europe
```

I would like to visualize this information with bar graphs. Here are the specific bar graphs that I'm trying to visualize:

- The number of 1s in BinVar-1 according to region
- The number of 1s in BinVar-2 according to region
- The number of unique values in MultiVar-1 according to region
- The number of unique values in MultiVar-2 according to region
- The number of rows per region

How do I do this in the `tidyverse` and `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to graph all three bar plots at once.
First group by `Region`, then `summarise` the data according to the question's specs and reshape from wide to long format. Finally, create an auxiliary variable `type` by removing the numbers from `BinVar-1`, etc. The plots are now straightforward.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  summarise(
    `BinVar-1` = sum(`BinVar-1`, na.rm = TRUE),
    `BinVar-2` = sum(`BinVar-2`, na.rm = TRUE),
    `MultiVar-1` = n_distinct(`MultiVar-1`, na.rm = TRUE),
    `MultiVar-2` = n_distinct(`MultiVar-2`, na.rm = TRUE),
    Count = n(),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Region) %>%
  mutate(type = sub("-\\d", "", name),
         type = factor(type, levels = c("BinVar", "MultiVar", "Count"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Region, value, fill = Region, group = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(~ type)
```

[image]

To graph one at a time, after `mutate` and just before `ggplot` filter by `type` and pipe to `ggplot`. For instance,

```
filter(type == "BinVar") %>%
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
BinVar-1 BinVar-2 MultiVar-1 MultiVar-2 Region
  0          0       0         0          Africa
  0          1       1         0          Europe
  0          1       2         0          Asia
  1          0       0         1          Asia
  1          0       3         2          Europe
  1          1       4         3          Africa
  0          0       5         4          Africa
  1          1       5         4          Asia
  0          0       3         2          Asia
  0          0       3         2          Europe
", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- tribble(
  ~BinVar1, ~BinVar2, ~MultiVar1, ~MultiVar2, ~Region,
  0, 0, 0, 0, "Africa",
  0, 1, 1, 0, "Europe",
  0, 1, 2, 0, "Asia",
  1, 0, 0, 1, "Asia",
  1, 0,3,  2, "Europe",
  1, 1, 4, 3, "Africa",
  0, 0, 5, 4, "Africa",
  1, 1, 5, 4, "Asia",
  0, 0, 3, 2, "Asia",
  0, 0, 3, 2, "Europe"
)
```

First, we can use `group_by()`, `filter()`, `distinct()`, and `summarise()` from the dplyr package.

- Count of 1s

```
# BinVar-1
df %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  filter(BinVar1 == 1) %>%
  summarise(n = n())

# BinVar-2
df %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  filter(BinVar2 == 1) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

- Count of unique values

```
# MultiVar-1
df %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  distinct(MultiVar1) %>%
  summarise(n = n())

# MultiVar-2
df %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  distinct(MultiVar2) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

- Count of rows

```
df %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

Then just use `ggplot()`. Here, I'm plotting the count of 1s in BinVar-1 according to region as an example.

```
df %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  filter(BinVar1 == 1) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Region, y = n)) +
  geom_col()
```